# Plot a scatter plot using plotly to see the relationship between the 'Budget' vs 'Gross values' using data visualisation concepts

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

Plot a scatter plot using plotly to see the relationship between the 'Budget' vs 'Gross values' according to different genres

Subtasks for customizations -

Subtask 1.1 - Try customizing your scatter plot with addition of marginal plots such as histogram, box plot or violin plot
Subtask 1.2 - Try linking hover-over data and try exploring the option to choose the genres dynamically

My Wrong Code:

```
#Sub task 1.1 marginal plots with an histogram
movies = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(movies, x="budget", y="Gross", color="genre_1", marginal_y="rug", marginal_x="histogram")
fig
```

Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-78b585ad2937> in <module>()
      1 #Sub task 1.1 marginal plots with an histogram
      2 movies = px.data.iris()
----> 3 fig = px.scatter(movies, x="budget", y="Gross", color="genre_1", marginal_y="rug", marginal_x="histogram")
      4 fig

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in scatter(data_frame, x, y, color, symbol, size, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, symbol_sequence, symbol_map, opacity, size_max, marginal_x, marginal_y, trendline, trendline_color_override, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
     51     In a scatter plot, each row of `data_frame` is represented by a symbol mark in 2D space.
     52     """
---> 53     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
     54 
     55 

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1092 
   1093     args, trace_specs, grouped_mappings, sizeref, show_colorbar = infer_config(
-> 1094         args, constructor, trace_patch
   1095     )
   1096     grouper = [x.grouper or one_group for x in grouped_mappings] or [one_group]

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in infer_config(args, constructor, trace_patch)
    975             all_attrables += [group_attr]
    976 
--> 977     args = build_dataframe(args, all_attrables, array_attrables)
    978 
    979     attrs = [k for k in attrables if k in args]

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in build_dataframe(args, attrables, array_attrables)
    897                             "\n To use the index, pass it in directly as `df.index`."
    898                         )
--> 899                     raise ValueError(err_msg)
    900                 if length and len(df_input[argument]) != length:
    901                     raise ValueError(

ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species', 'species_id'] but received: budget
```

Kindly assist Thanks, SB

Comment: What are `budget` and `movies` doing in the Iris dataset? I hope you know what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are loading an `iris` data frame:

```
movies = px.data.iris()
```

However, there are no columns named `"budget", "Gross"` as the error message says. You have to load a proper data frame which contains those columns -- your data.

```
movies = your_data_frame
```

Comment: ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species', 'species_id'] but received: budget

Comment: import plotly.express as px
movies = px.data.iris()
fig = My px.scatter(movies, x="budget", y="Gross", color="genre_1", marginal_y="rug", marginal_x="histogram")
fig